# VS Code Integrated Terminal Throws `Cannot find module` & `nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option`

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

It looks like this is a fairly common issue, but I've tried everything I can find and still can't seem to resolve it. If I load my terminal outside of VS Code it works fine, but the integrated terminal keeps throwing this when it starts:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '"/Users/me/Library/Application'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:12)
    at preloadModules (internal/bootstrap/node.js:601:7)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:273:9)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v10.16.3 --silent` to unset it.
```

I worked through the steps [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/editor/integrated-terminal.md#why-is-nvm-complaining-about-a-prefix-option-when-the-integrated-terminal-is-launched), which explain how to remove additional unwanted instances of npm/npx. The strange thing is that now `which npm` prints `/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/npm` before the `nvm` initialization script, which makes it seem like `nvm` has been loaded properly, but the `.zshrc` file is being run again, which might be causing the errors.

It looks like there's an extra `"` in the file path in the error message (`'"/Users/me/Library/Application'`), but I don't see any typos like that in my `nvm` initialization script, so it seems like maybe it's also a result of the initialization script being called twice?

Something else of note is that `node` and `npm` can't be found in the integrated terminal, but they work fine outside of VS Code.

I've also tried various other things like setting this in my VS Code settings: `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": []`, uninstalling and reinstalling node/nvm both manually and with homebrew. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Edit: I tried installing [VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and copying over my settings and the integrated terminal loads without any issues. So it seems like this might be fixed in a future release. I'll post an update after the update is available in VS Code to see if this issue goes away.*

Comment: Same issue for me. You're not alone.

Comment: Since the latest update it's also an issue for me I've not yet found any way around.

Comment: having an identical problem. been implementing solutions ive found online for hours now with no success.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this problem and I was just able to fix my issues by disabling auto attaching for debug in the VSCode settings. Hopefully I can re-enable this in the future since you mentioned there aren't issues with the latest insider release. I'm using a Bash shell by the way but hopefully this will help you as well.

```
"debug.node.autoAttach": "disabled",
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!

Comment: I checked the Insiders build and the integrated terminal is still working despite `autoAttach` being on, so it does seem to be fixed in an upcoming build.

Comment: Great to know, thanks for coming back and letting us know

Comment: same issue here

Comment: This was it! I had my setting to "off," which apparently does not mean the same thing as "disabled" in this context. Took me half a day to realize A) npm was only failing in VSC, and B) it started failing right after a VSC update. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted solution however it didnt work for me.

I had to use nvm to uninstall my versions, then just use nvm and install.
after that I didnt have the error.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue while attempting to debug a Next.JS node project. The suggested answer did not work for me as there was an issue with the debugger connecting to the node instance I was trying to run. I did 2 things to overcome the issue.

I use `nvm` for managing node versions. My default is `node v10` but I was running my Next.js project using `node v16`.

I went to the Next.JS website to look up their [documentation for Debugging](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging) and setup a `launch.config` in the `.vscode` folder using the suggested configuration that allows for Client Side, Server Side, or Full Stack Debugging. Note that Client Side debugging is expecting [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately the debugger still wasn't able to attach. While the debugger was still running, I ran `node -v` to see that the debugger launched a new terminal window using the default node version, which was `node v10`. Once I changed the version in the Debugger terminal to be `node v16` and then I ran `yarn dev` I was able to attach the debugger.

For me I will always be double checking or setting a default node version for a directory that I'm working in to prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score -2):

Try running this command in the Visual Studio Code terminal:

```
nvm use --delete-prefix v12.20.0 --silent
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).